# Create random numbers that is not in database as PASSWORD_HASH

Tags: php

I am trying to create random 5-digit number that is not in database as PASSWORD_HASH.

This is an example I have tried to make:

```
function check($num, $pwdcheck) {
    if(password_verify($num, $pwdcheck)) {
        return "exist";
    } else {
        return $num;
    }
}

function createLoginPassword() {
    /* Passwords from database */$pwds = array('$2y$10$gPenW2YPLzoZOKb/PZ8SC.UFh6C0cLALoO11x/8hjP3GeefMJ6sOu' /*<- Number 1*/, '$2y$10$iOOmAx4kJLNP5H91tfoaz.SarIA1byrUgEE8rtt9llqth5l4v5ACC' /*<- Number 2*/);
    foreach ($pwds as $result) {
        do {
            $output_password = rand(0,4);
        } while (check($output_password, $result) == "exist");
        $out = $output_password;
    }
    return $out;
}
echo createLoginPassword();
```

But it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't generate unique number that is not in array

Comment: What exactly "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: It doesn't generate unique number that is not in array

Comment: You de realize that `rand(0,4)` will return only 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: also, you do realize that password_hash won't produce the same hash for the same value when called multiple times

Comment: I know that rand(0,4) retuns numbers from 0 to 4, I made that for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function createLoginPassword() {
    // Passwords from database
    $pwds = [
        '$2y$10$gPenW2YPLzoZOKb/PZ8SC.UFh6C0cLALoO11x/8hjP3GeefMJ6sOu' /*<- Number 1*/,
        '$2y$10$iOOmAx4kJLNP5H91tfoaz.SarIA1byrUgEE8rtt9llqth5l4v5ACC' /*<- Number 2*/
    ];

    // while password exist, generate new one
    do {
        // generate 5-digit number
        $output = rand(10000, 99999);
    } while( !empty(array_filter($pwds, fn($pwd) => password_verify($output, $pwd))) );

    return $output;
}

echo createLoginPassword();
```

Comment: @Viljamas kindly take note of the arrow function `fn($pwd)` if you're not using PHP 7.4+